# Importing big ntriples file via workbench fails silently

Tags: graphdb

I'm trying to import a 2.2G file in ntriples format via the graphdb workbench. I leave all the settings in the dialogue as is (empty) and press *Import*. Dialogue goes away, but import doesn't start. No error message, no message on the console. My repository has all reasoning disabled (empty ruleset).

What should I do? Is there a better way to import big triple files into an existing repository?

Comment: Is this a local file on the server filesystem, or are you trying to upload it through the browser? (the latter won't work)

Comment: If this is a server file what's the output of `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7200/rest/data/import/server/myRepo?fileName=myFile.ttl'`, where you need to replace myRepo and myFile.ttl.

Answer (score 0):

To import very large files you cannot use upload through the browser. Here are some better ways:

- Use the LoadRdf tool: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data-using-the-loadrdf-tool.html
- Use the Preload tool: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data-using-preload.html
- Put the data in a designated repo on the server and use http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data-using-the-workbench.html#importing-server-files

  - As Vassil wrote, you can initiate this import programmatically using the REST API: `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7200/rest/data/import/server/myRepo?fileName=myFile.ttl`

See http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data.html for an overview of loading methods